# Is there a way to apply dynamic filters in R shiny similar to pivot in excel

Tags: r

Is there a way to put apply a filter for the below code. I have a dataframe below. When you run this code and click on Values under "Factors under the dataset" you can see the bar chart. Now as per the values in the filter for example when you select "sf" under filters the bar chart should change. Is this possible to achieve?

```
   df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 
                                 5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("asd", "dfg", "fgdsgd", 
                                                                         "fsd", "gdfgd", "gs", "sdfg", "sf"), class = "factor"), B = c(29L, 
                                                                                                                                       24L, 46L, 50L, 43L, 29L, 32L, 24L, 35L, 39L, 33L, 47L, 53L, 26L, 
                                                                                                                                       31L), C = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                             2L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("asd", "er", "fg", "gf", "gfd", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "gfg", "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), D = c(36L, 56L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                39L, 26L, 56L, 35L, 27L, 31L, 33L, 45L, 34L, 27L, 43L, 40L, 56L
                                                                                                                                                                                             ), E = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                9L, 8L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("asd", "er", "fg", "gf", "gfd", "gfg", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), F = c(44L, 34L, 37L, 23L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        37L, 51L, 28L, 36L, 33L, 31L, 39L, 43L, 25L, 37L, 43L)), class = 
              "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                          -15L))
theNames <- names(Filter(is.factor,df))
MyList  <- vector(mode = "list")
for(i in theNames){
MyList[[i]] <- levels(df[,i])
}
library(shiny) 
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML("
              label {
              width: 100%;
              background: lightgrey;
              padding: 5px;
              border-radius: 5px;
              }
              ")),
 tabsetPanel(
 tabPanel(
  "Factor_Bivariate_Analysis",sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(column(h6(selectInput("se4","Factors under the 
 dataset",choices = c("","Values"))),width = 5,offset = 
                        0),br(),column(h6(actionButton("Val","See the Values",width = 
                                                         200,offset=-1)),width = 5,offset = 0),br(),
               column(h6(selectInput("state", "Filters", MyList)),width = 5,offset = 0)),width = 
 1000),
    mainPanel(h5(plotOutput("Plot4",width = 1000,height = 
                              500),width=1000),h5(dataTableOutput("Plot5"),width=1000))
   )
 )
 )
 )
server <- function(input, output, session) {
Plot4 <- reactive(
if (input$se4 == "Values"){
  print(ggplot(df,aes(x=A,fill=A))+geom_bar(stat = "count"))
} else if (input$se4 == "NULL") {
  ""
})
output$Plot4 <- renderPlot(
{ 
  Plot4()
}
) 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? What are you trying to filter for?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what variable you want to filter by, the one used in the plot (`A`) or all variables. Also note that the filter select menu will be missing a section for `C` because all of `C`'s values are contained within `A` or `E`. But to filter, I would use a reactive function to first subset the data to user input and then pass that reactive as input to the plot making function. Applied to your app:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 2L), 
                                   .Label = c("asd", "dfg", "fgdsgd","fsd", "gdfgd", "gs", "sdfg", "sf"), class = "factor"), 
                     B = c(29L, 24L, 46L, 50L, 43L, 29L, 32L, 24L, 35L, 39L, 33L, 47L, 53L, 26L, 31L), 
                     C = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 4L), 
                                   .Label = c("asd", "er", "fg", "gf", "gfd", "gfg", "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"),
                     D = c(36L, 56L, 39L, 26L, 56L, 35L, 27L, 31L, 33L, 45L, 34L, 27L, 43L, 40L, 56L), 
                     E = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 4L), 
                                   .Label = c("asd", "er", "fg", "gf", "gfd", "gfg", "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"),
                     F = c(44L, 34L, 37L, 23L, 37L, 51L, 28L, 36L, 33L, 31L, 39L, 43L, 25L, 37L, 43L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))

theNames <- names(Filter(is.factor,df))
MyList  <- vector(mode = "list")
for(i in theNames){
  MyList[[i]] <- levels(df[,i])
}

ui <- fluidPage(tags$style(
  HTML(
    "
    label {
    width: 100%;
    background: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
    "
  )
  ),
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel(
    "Factor_Bivariate_Analysis",
    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(h6(
          selectInput("se4", "Factors under the
                      dataset", choices = c("", "Values"))
          ), width = 5, offset =
            0),
        br(),
        column(h6(
          actionButton("Val", "See the Values", width =
                         200, offset =
                         -1)
        ), width = 5, offset = 0),
        br(),
        column(h6(selectInput(
          "state", "Filters", MyList
        )), width = 5, offset = 0)
        ), width =
        1000
      ),
      mainPanel(
        h5(plotOutput(
          "Plot4", width = 1000, height =
            500
        ), width = 1000), h5(dataTableOutput("Plot5"), width = 1000)
      ))
  )))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  f_data <- reactive({
    wanted_case <- input$state
    cat("selected case ", wanted_case, "\n\n")
    if (wanted_case == "") {
      fd <- df
    } else {

      ##fd <- filter(df, A %in% wanted_case |C %in% wanted_case | E %in% wanted_case)
## EDIT to account for any number of factor variables
## assumes any filtering variable is a factor (i.e. not character)
      fd <- df %>%
        filter_if(.predicate = is.factor,
                  .vars_predicate = any_vars (. == wanted_case))
      print(fd)
    }

    return(fd)
  })

  Plot4 <- reactive({
    if (input$se4 == "Values") {
      print(ggplot(f_data(), aes(x = A, fill = A)) + geom_bar(stat = "count"))
    } else if (input$se4 == "NULL") {
      ""
    }
  })



  output$Plot4 <- renderPlot({
    Plot4()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks I will check now But in your code fd <- filter(df, A %in% wanted_case |C %in% wanted_case | E %in% wanted_case). Can we not a make loop here. Why because, in this data set, we have not only 3 factors and hence it is easy to write as you have shown, But if there are many? So i need to make this as a loop so what ever factors are there it should be take? Am i making sense?

Comment: May i know what cat("selected case ", wanted_case, "\n\n") is doing here? Little confused

Comment: It is just printing the selected value by the user to the console. Its useful for debugging. Same for `print(fd)`

Comment: See edits for the question in your first comment about generalizing the filter over any number of factor variables.

Comment: Hey @RahulH, if this answers your question, please accept the answer to close the thread.

Comment: Hi Teofil. In the above code I am confused with the line  ............filter_if(.predicate = is.factor,
                  .vars_predicate = any_vars (. == wanted_case))............. especially .==?

Comment: Well, we want to check whether entries in any of the columns equal the wanted case. `==` is for the logical check, `=` is for asignment. If you had more than 1 wanted case, you might need `%in%` instead of `==` in the check.